# why does the blank page top anchor in SharePoint 2010 not work?

Tags: html, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

Within a standard SharePoint publishing site, editing the homepage, entering lots of content and then placing a link to the top of the page using the following anchor link doesn't work:

```
<a href="#">back to top</a>
```

Clicking on the link above does nothing. However, other named anchors (such as

```
<a name="test"></a>
```

and

```
<a href="#test"></a>
```

work fine.

Has anyone come across this issue before?

Comment: Note that I've tried (with the same results) in both IE8 and FF3.6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<a href="#" />` [is not supposed to bring you to the top of the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/134845/href-for-javascript-links-or-javascriptvoid0). It targets the empty fragment and basically neuters the default behavior of the link most of the time.

I suspect your `<a name="#" />` solution is relying on an artifact of your browsers, because an anchor named `#` should be called `##` (or more probably `#%23`) in the `href` attribute of the link.

Since you have to create an anchor anyway, it might be best to give it a meaningful name like `TOP` and target it using `<a href="#TOP">back to top</a>`.

Answer (score 0):

I've gotten around it by placing

```
<a name="#"></a>
```

at the top of the page, but it would be good to find out why it doesn't work normally, and if there are any other nicer solutions out there.